# How to do unbuffered timeout read in Rust & tokio? (For telnet server handling)

Tags: rust, tcp, telnet, rust-tokio, tcpserver

I want to write a simple telnet server that can handle user key typing without having them press enter. This can be done in Python using the `telnetlib3` library with the following code:

```py
import asyncio

import telnetlib3
from telnetlib3 import TelnetReaderUnicode, TelnetWriterUnicode


async def shell(reader: TelnetReaderUnicode, writer: TelnetWriterUnicode):
    # Handle input function
    async def on_input(inp: str):
        # Switch case
        match inp:
            case '\x1b[C' | 'd':  # Right
                writer.write('Right pressed\r\n')
            case '\x1b[D' | 'a':  # Left
                writer.write('Left pressed\r\n')
            case '\x1b' | 'q' | '\x03':  # Escape or q or Ctrl+C
                writer.write('\r\nBye!\r\n')
                writer.close()
                return True
            case _:
                print(f'Unknown input: {repr(inp)}')
    
    # Listen input
    while True:
        inp: str = await reader.read(3)
        if inp and await on_input(inp):
            return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a new event loop, start the server and wait for it to close
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    coro = telnetlib3.create_server(port=2323, shell=shell)
    server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
    loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
```

In Rust, I created a similar TCP server using Tokio with read and write channels, but the input will only show up on the server when the telnet client press enter, no matter how small the buffer size is (e.g. I set it to 3 in this case). Is there a way to use unbuffered IO directly to gather client key presses without line breaks?

```rust
use std::io::Result;
use tokio::{
    io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt},
    net::TcpListener,
};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    const ADDR: &str = "127.0.0.1:2323";
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(ADDR).await?;

    println!("Server running on {ADDR}");

    while let Ok((mut socket, _addr)) = listener.accept().await {
        // Spawn a task to handle the socket
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let (mut reader, mut writer) = socket.split();

            // Put the terminal into raw mode to receive escape sequences
            writer.write_all(b"\x1B[?25l").await.unwrap(); // Hide the cursor
            writer.write_all(b"\x1B[?1049h").await.unwrap(); // Save cursor position and switch to alternate screen
            writer.flush().await.unwrap();

            // Send a welcome message to the client
            writer.write_all(b"Meow~\n").await.unwrap();

            // Read from the client until the connection is closed
            let mut buf = [0; 3];
            loop {
                // Print escaped characters for debug
                let n = reader.read(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
                for i in 0..n {
                    for e in std::ascii::escape_default(buf[i]) {
                        print!("{}", e as char);
                    }
                }

                writer
                    .write_all(
                        format!(
                            "\nReceived {n} bytes: {}",
                            String::from_utf8_lossy(&buf[..n])
                        )
                        .as_ref(),
                    )
                    .await
                    .unwrap();

                if n == 0 {
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: I edited your Rust code so that it runs and behaves like you described (as it was, it just immediately exited without accepting any connections). But your Python code also doesn't run correctly for me. Can you check if it works for you (I guess it's missing imports etc).

Comment: @PeterHall I just updated the python code to reflect an actual runnable example. It requires asyncio and telnetlib3. Thanks for the edit

Comment: Are you certain that your *client* is flushing content to the server to be read? Could you try using something like `netcat` to be certain?